# custom listview doesn't work in android

Tags: android, custom-lists

hi i create a app in android.
i receive data from internet but when i want show data in a custom list view my app crash and close. when i commentthis line: `list.setAdapter(adapter);`
my app works

**CustomAdapter class:**

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   implements                      OnClickListener {

        /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList data;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public Resources res;
        ListNews tempValues=null;
        int i=0;

        /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
        public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

            activity = a;
            data=d;
            res = resLocal;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
        public int getCount() {

            if(data.size()<=0)
                return 1;
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /********* Create a holder to contain inflated xml file elements ***********/
        public static class ViewHolder{

            public TextView text;
            public TextView text1;
            public TextView textWide;
            public ImageView image;

        }

        /*********** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row ***********/
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View vi=convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null){ 

                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null); 

                holder=new ViewHolder();
                holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

               /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                vi.setTag(holder);
            }
            else  
                holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

            if(data.size()<=0)
            {
                holder.text.setText("No Data");

            }
            else
            {
                /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
                tempValues=null;
                tempValues = (ListNews) data.get(position);


                 holder.text.setText(tempValues.getMenu_name());
                 holder.text1.setText(tempValues.getPage_title());
                 holder.image.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("com.androidexample.customlistview:drawable/"+tempValues.getImage(),null,null));

                 vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
            }
            return vi;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("CustomAdapter", "=====Row button clicked");
        }

        private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
            private int mPosition;

            OnItemClickListener(int position){
                 mPosition = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                CustomListViewAndroidExample sct = (CustomListViewAndroidExample)activity;
                sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
            }               
        }   
    }
```

**List news class**

```
public class ListNews {

    String language_id;
    String page_key;
    String page_title;
    String page_text;
    int menu_id;
    String menu_link;
    String menu_code;
    String menu_name;
    String ru = "";
    String Image = "";

    public String getLanguage_id() {
        return language_id;
    }
    public void setLanguage_id(String language_id) {
        this.language_id = language_id;
    }
    public String getPage_key() {
        return page_key;
    }
    public void setPage_key(String page_key) {
        this.page_key = page_key;
    }
    public String getPage_title() {
        return page_title;
    }
    public void setPage_title(String page_title) {
        this.page_title = page_title;
    }
    public String getPage_text() {
        return page_text;
    }
    public void setPage_text(String page_text) {
        this.page_text = page_text;
    }
    public int getMenu_id() {
        return menu_id;
    }
    public void setMenu_id(int menu_id) {
        this.menu_id = menu_id;
    }
    public String getMenu_link() {
        return menu_link;
    }
    public void setMenu_link(String menu_link) {
        this.menu_link = menu_link;
    }
    public String getMenu_code() {
        return menu_code;
    }
    public void setMenu_code(String menu_code) {
        this.menu_code = menu_code;
    }
    public String getMenu_name() {
        return menu_name;
    }
    public void setMenu_name(String menu_name) {
        this.menu_name = menu_name;
    }
    public String getRu() {
        return ru;
    }
    public void setRu(String ru) {
        this.ru = ru;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        Image = image;
    }
```

**login.java** // for show data in list view

```
package com.androidexample.customlistview;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.NetworkInfo.State;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity {

    Context context = Login.this;
    ListView list;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    public Login CustomListView = null;
    public ArrayList<ListNews> gettabledata,getdatabasedata;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Boolean b;
    Resources res;
    ArrayList<News> newsha;
    ArrayList<String> language_id, page_key, page_title, page_text, menu_id,
    menu_link, menu_code, menu_name, ru, im;
    JSONObject json_data;
    JSONArray jArray;
    DbGetData dbGetData3;
    Boolean boolean1;
    ContextWrapper wrapper = Login.this;
    News n;
    String data, url, msg, check, lan;
    ConnectivityManager conMan;
    State mobile, wifi;
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    int sizearray = 0, sizetable = 0, sizedb = 0;;
    ListNews td;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list_view_android_example);
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        CustomListView = Login.this;

        set();
        array();
        checkconnect();
        getdatafromdb();


    adapter = new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, gettabledata, res);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


    } // on create

    private void set() {
        try {
            boolean1 = doesDatabaseExist(wrapper, "test.db");

            data = "";
            url = "";
            gettabledata = new ArrayList<ListNews>();
            getdatabasedata = new ArrayList<ListNews>();
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            res = getResources();
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list5);
            data = "";
            url = "";


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    } // end set

    private static boolean doesDatabaseExist(ContextWrapper context, String dbName) {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
    private void array() {
        try {

            language_id = new ArrayList<String>();
            page_key = new ArrayList<String>();
            page_title = new ArrayList<String>();
            page_text = new ArrayList<String>();
            menu_id = new ArrayList<String>();
            menu_link = new ArrayList<String>();
            menu_code = new ArrayList<String>();
            menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();
            ru = new ArrayList<String>();
            im = new ArrayList<String>();

            language_id.clear();
            page_key.clear();
            page_title.clear();
            page_text.clear();
            menu_id.clear();
            menu_link.clear();
            menu_code.clear();
            menu_name.clear();
            ru.clear();
            im.clear();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }
    }

    private void getdatafromdb() {

        try {
            url = "my url address";

            dbGetData3 = new DbGetData();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    data = dbGetData3.getDataFromDB(url);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            newsha = parseJSON3(data);                          
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public ArrayList<News> parseJSON3(String result) {
        ArrayList<News> userha = new ArrayList<News>();
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                n = new News();

                n.setLanguage_id(json_data.getString("language_id"));
                language_id.add(json_data.getString("language_id"));

                n.setPage_key(json_data.getString("page_key"));
                page_key.add(json_data.getString("page_key"));

                n.setPage_title(json_data.getString("page_title"));
                page_title.add(json_data.getString("page_title"));

                n.setPage_text(json_data.getString("page_text"));
                page_text.add(json_data.getString("page_text"));

                n.setMenu_id(json_data.getInt("menu_id"));
                menu_id.add(String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("menu_id")));

                n.setMenu_link(json_data.getString("menu_link"));
                menu_link.add(json_data.getString("menu_link"));

                n.setMenu_code(json_data.getString("menu_code"));
                menu_code.add(json_data.getString("menu_code"));

                n.setMenu_name(json_data.getString("menu_name"));
                menu_name.add(json_data.getString("menu_name"));

                ru.add("ak3");
                im.add("image5");

                userha.add(n);
            }
            sizearray = language_id.size();
            if (sizearray <= 0) {
                getdatafromdb();
            } else {

              sizedb = sizearray;
            }
            if (boolean1) {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  getFromTable();
                  if (sizedb != sizetable) {
                      Toast.makeText(context, "size is not eqal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      context.deleteDatabase("test.db");
                      createTable();
                }
                  else {
                      Toast.makeText(context, "size is eqal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } else {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  createTable();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
        return userha;
    }

    private void getFromTable() {

        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("test.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from tb", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                td = new ListNews();

                td.setLanguage_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("language_id")));
                td.setPage_key(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("page_key")));
                td.setPage_title(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("page_title")));
                td.setPage_text(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("page_text")));
                td.setMenu_id(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("menu_id")));
                td.setMenu_link(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("menu_link")));
                td.setMenu_code(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("menu_code")));
                td.setMenu_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("menu_name")));
                td.setRu(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ru")));
                td.setImage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image")));

                getdatabasedata.add(td);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            Toast.makeText(CustomListView, "get data from table.......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        sizetable = getdatabasedata.size();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Database size: " + String.valueOf(sizetable),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void createTable() {

        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("test.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        sizetable = 0;
        getdatabasedata.clear();

        db.execSQL("create table if not exists tb ("
                + "language_id NVARCHAR NOT NULL,"
                + "page_key NVARCHAR NOT NULL,"
                + "page_title NVARCHAR NOT NULL,"
                + "page_text NVARCHAR NOT NULL,"
                + "menu_id NVARCHAR NOT NULL,"
                + "menu_link NVARCHAR NOT NULL,"
                + "menu_code NVARCHAR NOT NULL,"
                + "menu_name NVARCHAR NOT NULL,"
                + "ru NVARCHAR NOT NULL,"
                + "image NVARCHAR NOT NULL);");

        Toast.makeText(context, "Table created.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.close();
        addToTable();
    }

    private void addToTable() {

        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("test.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < sizearray; i++) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("language_id", language_id.get(i));
            values.put("page_key", page_key.get(i));
            values.put("page_title", page_title.get(i));
            values.put("page_text", page_text.get(i));
            values.put("menu_id", menu_id.get(i));
            values.put("menu_link", menu_link.get(i));
            values.put("menu_code", menu_code.get(i));
            values.put("menu_name", menu_name.get(i));
            values.put("ru", ru.get(i));
            values.put("image", im.get(i));

            db.insert("tb", null, values);
        }
        db.close();
        getFromTable();

    }

    public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {
        ListNews tempValues = (ListNews) gettabledata.get(mPosition);

        Toast.makeText(
                CustomListView,
                "" + tempValues.getMenu_name() + " \nImage: "
                        + tempValues.getPage_title() + " \nUrl: "
                        + tempValues.getPage_text(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void checkconnect() {
        try {
            conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Login.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();
            wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();
            if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                    || mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {

                } else if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                    || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
} else {
                // Login.this.finish();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**login.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**tabitem** // listview items

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/bar_bg"
    android:paddingTop="0dip" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="3dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="82dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingTop="0dp" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textDirection="rtl" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                        android:layout_span="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivru"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

log error

```
08-11 01:09:05.267: E/InputDispatcher(1720): Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
08-11 01:09:05.357: E/InputDispatcher(1720): Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
08-11 01:09:05.567: E/AndroidRuntime(4456): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.androidexample.customlistview
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456): Process: com.androidexample.customlistview, PID: 4456
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidexample.customlistview/com.androidexample.customlistview.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at com.androidexample.customlistview.Login.onCreate(Login.java:72)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-11 01:09:05.577: E/AndroidRuntime(4456):     ... 11 more
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.androidexample.customlistview
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472): Process: com.androidexample.customlistview, PID: 4472
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidexample.customlistview/com.androidexample.customlistview.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at com.androidexample.customlistview.Login.onCreate(Login.java:72)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-11 01:09:05.677: E/AndroidRuntime(4472):     ... 11 more
08-11 01:09:05.757: E/AndroidRuntime(4486): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.androidexample.customlistview
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486): Process: com.androidexample.customlistview, PID: 4486
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidexample.customlistview/com.androidexample.customlistview.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at com.androidexample.customlistview.Login.onCreate(Login.java:72)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-11 01:09:05.787: E/AndroidRuntime(4486):     ... 11 more
08-11 01:09:47.127: E/cutils-trace(4503): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-11 01:09:47.137: E/memtrack(4503): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-11 01:09:47.137: E/android.os.Debug(4503): failed to load memtrack module: -2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your onCreate() like below

```
 ListView mListView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();

 mListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list5)

        set();
        array();
        checkconnect();
        getdatafromdb();

   if(gettabledata!=null)
   {
   adapter = new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, gettabledata, res);
   }
 else
   {
    adapter = null;
   }
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, gettabledata, res);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: @user2675784  if my answer is helpful to resolve the issue then mark it as accepted, it may help some one in future :)

Answer (score 0):

You have created `list5` in login.xml but your are using `activity_custom_list_view_android_example` as activity view. So you are getting `NPE` when you use list object. You have to change `activity_custom_list_view_android_example` to `login`
i.e `setContentView(R.layout.login);`

Comment: hi tankyou for you answer. Now my data dose not show in list view (size array is 0 in custom listview adapter )
where i should add list.setAdapter(adapter);